# iOS / Cocoa: using an URL as a key in a NSDictionary

Tags: caching, nsdictionary, nsurl

For an application I'm working on I have a class that deals with the requests sent to a webservice. To reduce traffic load I want to cache most of the requests and their results (at least for the content that won't change often). A request is uniquely identified by the URL used, so I want to use the URL as a key.

In a previous project I worked on I used to create a md5 hash of the URL to function as a key. I've began wondering how safe this approach is, since apparently there's quite a chance that 2 different URL's produce the same hashed value.

Can anyone suggest a safer approach, or should I still stick with md5 hashes of the URL to function as a key in my cache dictionary?

Comment: MD5 and "since apparently there's quite a change that 2 different URL's produce the same hashed value"? Really? Please give me an example, I think you won the lottery!

Comment: Why don’t you use `NSURL` objects as the dictionary keys?

Comment: How are you making those requests? ASI? Or NSURLConnections?

Comment: @Nick MD5 is susceptible to collision attacks, although I agree that would be rather unlikely in the OP situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an `NSMutableDictionary`, with the URLs (as `NSString`s) for the dictionary keys. `NSDictionary` (and `NSMutableDictionary`) are almost certainly implemented with some sort of hash table internally, but they will take care of any hash duplicate issues. If you give it a unique key, it will store it properly.

Unless you're sure that `NSMutableDictionary` is too slow for you needs (which it almost certainly won't be), you don't need to worry about hashing, collisions or anything like that. Just stick the data in your dictionary with a unique key (the URL).

Comment: Yeah, I sticked with the URL. I just had a brainf*ck. There was no reason whatsoever to use hashed URLs - I only needed those in the past when I used a distinct file for each cached object, but currently all objects are saved in one single file so the issue is actually nonexistent.

Comment: "with the URLs (as `NSStrings`) for the dictionary keys" Why? Is there any reason why you wouldn't use the `NSURL` as key directly?

Comment: @ErikB one reason is that you can represent the same absolute URL in multiple ways using `NSURL` using different combinations of `baseURL` and `relativeToURL`. I haven't actually checked to see if `NSURL`s created in this way are considered to be `equal`, but to avoid that possibility, using the URLs canonical representation (an absolute string) avoids the issue entirely.

Comment: why not use the NSURL's directly as keys? any "hashable"  NSObject can serve as key, and NSURL is.  whichever hash it uses internally I don't really care, and I believe Apple (knowing their internals) would provide better hash for an NSURL than what I could ever come up with.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest looking at the [Understanding Cache Access](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/CachePolicies.html) chapter of the URL Loading System Programming Guide.

If that won't suffice I would stick to md5 as a key. I don't think that you expose any vulnerability of your app to potential attackers. How could harm be done?